# Mathematic D and Dt not behaving properly?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The derivative functions D and Dt don't appear to be functioning as advertised.
Following the first example in the "Properties and Relations" section of http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Constants.html I have:

```
In[1]:= {Dt[ax^2 + b, x, Constants -> {a, b}], D[ax^2 + b, x]}

Out[1]= {2 ax Dt[ax, x, Constants -> {a, b}], 0}
```

I've duplicated the input, but the output is totally different.  How do I get the expected output `{ 2 a x, 2 a x}`?

I am using Mathematica 8.0.1.0 64-bit as installed at Rutgers University.

Answer (score 8):

You need a space between `a` and `x`, otherwise it thinks you're talking about a variable named `ax`:

```
In[2]:= {Dt[a x^2 + b, x, Constants -> {a, b}], D[a x^2 + b, x]}

Out[2]= {2 a x, 2 a x}
```

Answer (score 3):

(*I realize this isn't really answering the OP's question. But given the level of the question, along with OP's desire to use the `Contants` option, the following info may prove useful for others in the future.*)

## My 2 cents on `Dt`.

IMO, using the `Constants` option is less than ideal---mainly because it produces messy output. For example:

```
In[1]:= Dt[x^a y^b, Constants -> {a, b}]

Out[1]= a x^(-1 + a) y^b Dt[x, Constants -> {a, b}] + 
 b x^a y^(-1 + b) Dt[y, Constants -> {a, b}]
```

*Am I the only one who finds the above behavior annoying/redundant? Is there a practical reason for this design?* If so, please educate me... **:)**

## Alternative approaches:

If you don't want to use the `Constants` option, here are some alternative approaches.

### Use UpValues to force constants.

```
In[2]:= Remove[a, b];
        a /: Dt[a] = 0;
        b /: Dt[b] = 0;
        Dt[x^a y^b]

Out[5]= a x^(-1 + a) y^b Dt[x] + b x^a y^(-1 + b) Dt[y]
```

### Use Attributes. (i.e., give certain symbols the `Constant` `Attribute`.

```
In[6]:= Remove[a, b];
        SetAttributes[{a, b}, Constant];
        Dt[x^a y^b]

Out[8]= a x^(-1 + a) y^b Dt[x] + b x^a y^(-1 + b) Dt[y]
```

### Use Rules to alter the output of the main Dt[] expression.

```
In[9]:= Remove[a, b];
        Dt[x^a y^b] /. Dt[a] -> 0 /. Dt[b] -> 0

Out[10]= a x^(-1 + a) y^b Dt[x] + b x^a y^(-1 + b) Dt[y]
```